# Erroneous successful validation by JSON-schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

The fields in nodes depend on the value of entity. That is, if entity = "pd", then nodes has some fields, while entity = " top " - nodes has completely different fields, despite the fact that they are strictly required. For some reason, the JSON string is accepted by the valid schema, even if there are no fields defined in nodes as required. I already entire head broke, where can be mistake in the most scheme?
JSON-schema:

```
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "The Root Schema",
  "required": [
    "virtual"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "virtual": {
      "$id": "#/properties/virtual",
      "type": "array",
      "title": "The Virtual Schema",
      "items": {
        "$id": "#/properties/virtual/items",
        "type": "object",
        "title": "The Items Schema",
        "required": [
          "type",
          "path",
          "entity",
          "nodes"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "$id": "#/properties/virtual/items/properties/type",
            "type": "string",
            "title": "The Type Schema",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "bus"
            ],
            "pattern": "^(.*)$"
          },
          "path": {
            "$id": "#/properties/virtual/items/properties/path",
            "type": "string",
            "title": "The Path Schema",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "VBUS2"
            ],
            "pattern": "^(.*)$"
          },
          "entity": {
            "$id": "#/properties/virtual/items/properties/entity",
            "type": "string",
            "title": "The Entity Schema",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "topaz"
            ],
            "enum": ["pde", "topaz"],
            "pattern": "^(.*)$"
          },
          "nodes": {
            "$id": "#/properties/virtual/items/properties/nodes",
            "type": "array",
            "title": "The Nodes Schema",
            "items": {
                "$id": "#/properties/virtual/items/properties/nodes/items",
                "type": "object",
                "title": "The Items Schema"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {       
        "if": {
            "properties": { "virtual": { "properties": { "entity": { "const": "topaz" } } } } 
        },
        "then": {
            "properties": { 
                "virtual": { 
                    "properties": { 
                        "nodes": {  
                            "items": {
                                "required": [
                                    "uid",
                                    "utype",
                                    "uaddress",
                                    "unozzles"
                                ],
                                "properties": {
                                    "uid": {
                                        "$id": "#/properties/virtual/items/properties/nodes/items/properties/uid",
                                        "type": "integer",
                                        "title": "The Uid Schema",
                                        "default": 0,
                                        "examples": [
                                            1
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "utype": {
                                        "$id": "#/properties/virtual/items/properties/nodes/items/properties/utype",
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "title": "The Utype Schema",
                                        "default": "",
                                        "examples": [
                                            "dispenser"
                                        ],
                                        "pattern": "^(.*)$" 
                                    },
                                    "uaddress": {
                                        "$id": "#/properties/virtual/items/properties/nodes/items/properties/uaddress",
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "title": "The Uaddress Schema",
                                        "default": "",
                                        "examples": [
                                            "false"
                                        ],
                                        "pattern": "^(.*)$"
                                    },
                                    "unozzles": {
                                        "$id": "#/properties/virtual/items/properties/nodes/items/properties/unozzles",
                                        "type": "boolean",
                                        "title": "The Unozzles Schema",
                                        "default": false,
                                        "examples": [
                                            false
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "if": { 
            "properties": { "virtual": { "properties": { "entity": { "const" : "pde" } } } }
        },
        "then": {
            "properties": {
                "virtual": {
                    "properties": {
                        "nodes": {
                            "items": {
                                "required": [                                   
                                    "id",
                                    "type",
                                    "address",
                                    "nozzles"
                                ],
                                "properties": {
                                    "id": {                     
                                        "$id": "#/properties/virtual/items/properties/nodes/items/properties/id",
                                            "type": "string",
                                            "title": "The Id Schema",
                                            "default": "",
                                            "examples": [
                                                "vrt_1"
                                            ],
                                        "pattern": "^(.*)$"
                                    },
                                    "type": {
                                        "$id": "#/properties/virtual/items/properties/nodes/items/properties/type",
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "title": "The Type Schema",
                                        "default": "",
                                        "examples": [
                                            "dispenser"
                                        ],
                                        "pattern": "^(.*)$"
                                    },
                                    "address": {
                                        "$id": "#/properties/virtual/items/properties/nodes/items/properties/address",
                                        "type": "integer",
                                        "title": "The Address Schema",
                                        "default": 0,
                                        "examples": [
                                            1
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "nozzles": {
                                        "$id": "#/properties/virtual/items/properties/nodes/items/properties/nozzles",
                                        "type": "array",
                                        "title": "The Nozzles Schema",
                                        "items": {
                                            "$id": "#/properties/virtual/items/properties/nodes/items/properties/nozzles/items",
                                            "type": "integer",
                                            "title": "The Items Schema",
                                            "default": 0,
                                            "examples": [
                                                1,
                                                2,
                                                3
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }                                           
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  ]  
}
```

This JSON is valid:

```
{
    "virtual": [
        {
            "type": "bus",
            "path": "VUS1",
            "entity": "pde",
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": "vrt_1",
                    "type": "string",
                    "address": 1,
                    "nozzles": [1, 2, 3]
                },
                {
                    "id": "vrt_2",
                    "type": "string",
                    "address": 2,
                    "nozzles": [1, 2, 3]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "bus",
            "path": "VUS2",
            "entity": "topaz",
            "nodes": [          
                {
                    "uid": 1,
                    "utype": "string",
                    "uaddress": "false",
                    "unozzles": false
                },
                {
                    "uid": "vrt_1",
                    "utype": "string",
                    "uaddress": "false",
                    "unozzles": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And this JSON should not be applied, but is considered valid:

```
{
    "virtual": [
        {
            "type": "bus",
            "path": "VUS1",
            "entity": "pde",
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id_not_valid": "failure",
                    "type": 1,
                    "address": false,
                    "nozzles": [1, 2, 3]
                },
                {
                    "id": "vrt_2",
                    "type": "string",
                    "address": false,
                    "nozzles": [1, 2, 3]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "bus",
            "path": "VUS2",
            "entity": "topaz",
            "nodes": [          
                {
                    "uid_not_valid": "failure",
                    "utype": 1,
                    "uaddress": "false",
                    "unozzles": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In theory, the second JSON should not be validated. For several reasons:

1. For entity= "pd", the required fields are "id", "type"," address "and"nozzles". In the second line of JSON instead the field "id" is replaced by the field "id_not_valid" - > the obligatory field " id " is absent and validation has to end in failure. The same for entity="top" - "the uid" is replaced by "id_not_valid"
2. For entity= "pd", the address field is of type token, in the second JSON line it is set to false, which corresponds to the type "boolean", but validation still takes place (the same if you assign an array or string value to address). For entity="top" type, the type is string, but the integer value 1 assigned to it is also assumed by the validator to be the correct string.

But the online validators on the links below say that everything is OK and both JSON conform to the scheme.

[The first site](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/)

[Second site](https://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/)

[The third website](https://extendsclass.com/json-schema-validator.html)

So I believe there is an error in the scheme.
The scheme itself was made by this example [Example of JSON schema compilation](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html)

Any comments and tips on fixing JSON-schema, please

Comment: Could you edit your theory of why the second instance should fail, please?  I'm not sure that it came out quite as you intended.

Comment: Edited the question. I hope this make it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema *is* malformed.

(I'm ignoring the fact that the schema states `entity` should be `"pde"` or `"topaz"`, but the instances have `"pd"` and `"top"`.  I assume this is a typo.)

Inside the `anyOf`, you have two items, each with an `if` conditional keyword.  The schema presented by this keyword is

```
{
  "properties": {
    "virtual": {
      "properties": {
        "entity": {
          "const": "topaz"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is saying that *if* `virtual` has an `entity` property, then it should be `"topaz"`.  But the way that `properties` works is that it only fails validation *if the instance is an object*.  However in `#/properties`, you declare that `virtual` should be an an array of objects where *each item* contains an `entity` property.

Since `virtual` is an array in your instance, none of the `if` condition keywords in the `anyOf` pass, so they defer to the `else` keywords for those subschemas, which don't exist (so the pass by default).  This results in both subschemas for the `anyOf` passing.

I *think* what you're trying to do is validate each of the items inside the array based on the value of the `entity` property for that item.  This means that you could have both a `pde` item and a `topaz` item in the array.

To do this you need to isolate where the variance is.  In your case, it's the item level inside the `virtual` array.  This is where you need to put your `anyOf`.

So you'll want to add your `anyOf` to `#/properties/virtual/items`.  This is the only point in the schema where an `if`/`then` construct can key off of the `entity` property and enforce the `nodes` property.

---

**Edit** Things I would change

1. Remove all of the internal `$id` declarations.  They only reiterate the location in the document and provide no additional functionality.
2. Remove the `type` and `pattern` declarations from `entity`.  `enum` is sufficient here because it declares that the values must be one of the items in the array.  Since these are both strings and match the given pattern, those keywords are redundant.
3. Move the `anyOf` alongside the `properties` keyword inside `virtual` and change it to a `oneOf`.  This is the most specific location where you can access both the `entities` property and the `nodes` property.  Changing it to a `oneOf` ensures that exactly one can be true.
4. Drop the `if`/`then` construct and just include the constant value in the `then` portion.

In the end, it would be structured something like this:

```
{
  ... ,
  "properties": {
    "virtual": {
      "type": "array",
      "title": "The Virtual Schema",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "The Items Schema",
        "required": [ "type", "path", "entity", "nodes" ],
        "properties": {
          "type": { ... },
          "path": { ... },
          "entity": {
            "title": "The Entity Schema",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
              "topaz"
            ],
            "enum": ["pde", "topaz"]
          }
        },
        "oneOf": [
            {
                "properties": {
                    "entity": {"const": "topaz"},
                    "nodes": { ... }
                }
            },
            {
                "properties": {
                    "entity": {"const": "pde"},
                    "nodes": { ... }
                }
            }
        ]
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Here, we're declaring that the items within the `virtual` array must be objects requiring 4 properties: `type`, `path`, `entity`, and `nodes`.  We explicitly define `type`, `path`, `entity` using the `properties` keyword.  But we conditionally define the `nodes` property using the `oneOf` and specifying a constant value for the `entity` property in each case.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, sorry about that. I agree, the scheme looks terrible. My first acquaintance with them. In a whole, I roughly understood that you had in view, but not can achieve outcome on their own. Could you schematically (I do not ask to make a scheme for yourself) show the correct option?

Comment: Edited with my suggestions.